Can a custom slug be created in WordPress when the URL structure for the site is like this: https://www.example.com/post_title?
I have a WordPress website with the URL structure of its posts like this: https://www.example.com/post_title, and I want to create a category named "breaking" where all posts in this category are displayed with this URL format: https://www.example.com/breaking/post_title. I've tried various plugins but encountered issues. Is it possible to write some code in the functions.php file to achieve this?
Of course, previously, I wrote the following code, which only changes the URL but doesn't display the page and returns a 404 error.
function custom_category_permalink_structure($permalink, $post, $leavename) {
    if (in_category('breaking', $post)) {
        $permalink = trailingslashit(home_url('/mag/breaking/' . $post->post_name));
    }
    return $permalink;
}
add_filter('post_link', 'custom_category_permalink_structure', 10, 3);


I think you should setting in wordpress admin.
setting => Permalink =>  Custom Structure
and add "/%category%/%postname%/"

I know about this setting but i want to do this setting just for .../breaking not all links in my website
